# ejb class is not found in glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, ejb

I have JAVA EE Application I,m trying to call EJB from servelate but everytime I have this error

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
```

I check the glassfish log I see this

```
  SEVERE:   Class [ Lejbexercises/StatlessFundManagerBean; ] not found. Error while loading [ class controllers.TestStatelessEJB ]

    ejb class
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    package ejbexercises;

    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.ejb.LocalBean;

    /**
     *
     * @author
     */
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class StatlessFundManagerBean {

       public double addFunds(double balance, double amount) {
            balance += amount;
            return balance;
        }

        public double withdrawFunds(double balance, double amount) {
            if (balance < 0) {
                return 0.0;
            } else {
                balance -= amount;
                return balance;
            }
        }
    }


/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package controllers;

import ejbexercises.StatlessFundManagerBean;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */

@WebServlet(name = "TestStatelessEJB", urlPatterns = {"/TestStatelessEJB"})
public class TestStatelessEJB extends HttpServlet {

   @EJB(name = "sfm")
 private StatlessFundManagerBean sfm;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
                double balance = 1200;
                balance = (double) sfm.addFunds(balance, Double.parseDouble("1200"));
                out.println("1st balance=" + balance );
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From EJB Documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb30/annotations.html#wp1416481):

name - Specifies the name by which the referenced EJB is to be looked up in the environment.

You are using (name = "sfm") and this means that container will lookup bean known to it as "sfm" which is wrong in your case unless you have defined bean name in beans.xml (but you didn't mention it, so I assume, you haven't).

Just remove the (name="sfm ) part and do not forget to redeploy your app.

Comment: still have SEVERE:   Class [ Lejbexercises/StatlessFundManagerBean; ] not found. Error while loading [ class controllers.TestStatelessEJB ]

Comment: Can you redeploy your app and post server log lines where EJB is initalized. This can be deployment issue. And how are you trying to acces web page?

Comment: I just reproduced your example. Everything works fine (without name="sfm"). Looking closer i've noticed that your first problem is that you can not access servlet at all. Make sure you type right address in your browser. It is http://localhost:8080/Lejbexercises/TestStatelessEJB in my case

Comment: just I want to ask?is you project located in my doc\netbeansProjects ??

Comment: No, I'm using Eclipse